# Calling a QT Button (C++) From the External Python Script

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am working on a project that is mainly written on Python, but the part where the camera captures are being processed is in a QT project (C++).

For ex:
There is a `start` button in the QT which activates several functions that are written in C++:

in **main.qml:**

```
Button {
    id: startbutton
    x: 910
    y: 822
    text: qsTr("Start")

    onPressed: {
        VideoStreamer.startcapturing()
    }
}
```

For now, I am clicking on this button manually, but I need to write a function that activates this button whenever it is needed in the **Python algorithm**.

**-->** So the Python script should call the start button somehow.

I've read about pipes but I couldn't implement anything, actually I don't even know whether I should focus on the communication between QT and Python or C++ and Python.

Can you help me with this using these spesific codes above?

***Notes:***
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

**All the projects are in the same PC.**

Comment: This seems like a huge [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why not just change the C++ application to start capturing when it is started?

Comment: The algorithm contains some image-processing problems, so it is more like 'taking the picture of that moment' only when it is needed. Not like recording something from start to end. And I need this communication for some future reasons too.

Comment: You might look at FrogLogic’s program named Squish, it is used to drive automated testing of Qt GUI apps, including programmatically pressing their buttons.

Answer (score 2):

A full answer is completely out of scope for SO, but you are basically asking "how do I retrofit this Qt application to support inter-process communication".

Some options:

- Have the Qt application listen for commands on a TCP or Unix socket. You can either invent a protocol yourself (for example simple JSON objects with a length field in front or a simple HTTP server) or look at established IPC protocols such as gRPC, Thrift and capnproto.
- Make the two applications communicate over DBus, which is well-suited to simple one-way commands.

In all cases, you will have to retrofit the Qt application to emit the appropriate internal signals when a command arrives.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Can you be more spesific with the second option? I saw some examples on PyQT but my qt part is not on python. Can you write maybe a pseudo code just to show how to use it base on my button?

Comment: No, that would involve me basically knowing about your entire Qt application, which I don't.